# Duplicate Word Document Using OpenXML While Open Original Document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, word-addins

I need to create a same copy of existing word document and open it as another instance while the original first document being opened. The second word document do not save but user may have the option to save it or not.

This need to be done using OpenXML.

I will attached here the current implementation. This implementation is having several issues.

1. The first document need to close first before use it in WordprocessingDocument using statement.
2. The second newly created document need to save in local folder.

**Code Initiation**

```
 var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
            doc.Save();
            string fileName = doc.FullName;
            doc.Close();
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use OpenXML ? With Interop you could simply:

- Open the existing document
- Copy everything within the document range
- Create a new document
- Paste the other document in the new one

It's done quickly and does the job perfectly

Comment: I have a solution with interop,but here i need to do it using openxml

Comment: The problem is OpenXml manipulates package and not word application itself, that's why you have to save it and can't let it "open", because there is no word application running.

Could you explain why do you need it to be done only with openxml?

Comment: Our expectation is to adding comments in to new duplicated word instance which need to add comments.Currently we done it using normal interop services. But it takes some time to add comments in to the duplicated new document.So we might thing about a way of speed up the adding comments part using openxml. If it is not effective, do we have another way around to boost up of large document adding comments.

Comment: If your problem with interop is a speed one, you should first identify what takes time (duplication ? opening ? locate the position of insertion ? the insertion itself ?). The optimization depends of the problem